# Upgrading Ubuntu 10.04 LTS Lucid Lynx to 12.04

Tags: 12.04, 10.04

Does upgrading ubuntu also upgrades the kernel? OR Is better to remove old ubuntu and install latest one because I want latest updated version of linux OS for compiling vlc android project

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Q1. Does upgrading ubuntu also upgrades the kernel?*

Yes It will upgrade your kernel too, but If you want to hold your kernel with out any update/upgrade , then yes you can do that.

Bottom-line: Yes upgrade will give a kernel update too.

*Q2. Is better to remove old Ubuntu and install latest one.*

Generally If you do fresh install , then again you have to install & configure everything. Like Applications and others.

If you upgrade , you wont lost your data,programs or applications and other modifications you made.

But sometimes upgrades do failed but its not often.

Bottom-line: Its up to you.

Comment: then no need to install it i think just upgrading will solve the problem

Comment: r u sure that it will upgrade the kernel

Comment: @RahulMatte yes it is . check this out https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/LTSEnablementStack

Comment: @RahulMatte Ubuntu 10.04 is EOL. Check the link I provided in comment. You will need to modify your apt.conf to point to old-releases.ubuntu.com to upgrade. You might be better off doing a fresh install of 14.04.